# targetSquare.isMounted does not work for LateInitializationError

Tags: flame

I have a `late SquareComponent targetSquare;` now I wanna check it's bool value in update method like this:

```
@override
  Future<void> update(double dt) async {
    if (targetSquare.isMounted) {
        if (!targetSquare.resourceIsFinished) {
          targetGridPosition = currentGridPosition;
        } else {
          currentGridPosition = targetGridPosition;
        }
      }
  }
```

And I met the error `Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'targetSquare' has not been initialized.` I don't know why it happens, since I already add this `targetSquare.isMounted` , what should I do if this `targetSquare` is not initialized? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you have not set the `targetSquare` variable before the `update`-loop starts running.

You could solve it by setting that variable in either `onLoad` or `onMount`, like this:

```dart
class YourComponent extends Component {
  late SquareComponent targetSquare;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    targetSquare = SquareComponent(...);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Also, don't have your `update` method as `async`, that will give all kinds of trouble.

Update:
Here's how you can do it with a nullable instead:

```dart
class YourComponent extends Component {
  SquareComponent? targetSquare;

  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    targetSquare = SquareComponent(...);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    if (targetSquare != null) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi spydon, thanks for the reply, my issue is this targetSquare is not initialized yet when the YourComponent is onload, but I need to use it after targetSquare is initialized in update, so I thought use targetSquare.isMounted to check if this targetSquare has already variable.

Comment: isMounted can't check that, what you can do is make it a nullable instead of late, I'll update my answer with a solution like that too.